# Interpolate Multiple Data With Kriging In ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, kriging, iteration, multi-values

I am having problems building a model for running interpolation on multiple data using the Kriging method.

I have followed these steps:

1. Convert multiple data to geodatabase file
2. Used iteration on these feature classes
3. Plot Kriging tools in model

One of the inputs for the Kriging tool is a Z Value, it does not appear in the options, how can I include it?

I have attached my model

[image]

I am running in ArcMap 10.2

[image]

i just create new model concept and still Z value is empty

[image]

Comment: Just be sure that the (Feature type) in (iterate feature classes) is point and your feature class has a field with z values. also, rename the output of the (iterate feature classes) to  inline variable (%Name%)

Comment: @Moh thanks for your suggest, all suggest i have checked in my model, still Z values not exist. All data for input have z values and out of the iteration file has rename inline variable too. Any have suggest. Thanks

Comment: Is the z field numeric or text type?

Comment: Z field numeric type @Moh